# Testing a replaced element within a directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, jasmine

I'm working on creating a directive to dynamically generate DOM elements based on model data. While I can get it to work properly, I am having issues accurately testing replacing the root node element via Jasmine.

I am able to work around this right now by simply inserting the new node as a child and leaving the parent element. Ideally I would like to replace it entirely.

I know about the directive `replace: true` option, however, I need the template to have access to scope data that will determine what element will be generated.

Below is a simple directive example and the test code. The test will fail, but actually works properly on the client. Does anyone have any ideas or suggestions?

Is there a better way of generating elements that are generated from scope data?

**Directive**

```
'use strict';

angular.module( 'myApp', [ ] )
.directive('myReplace', function( $compile ) {
  var postLink, preLink;

  postLink = function( scope, element ) {
    /**
     * I need to do the replacement here because the generated
     * element needs access to the scope.
     */
    var newEle;
    element.html(
      '<p>
        I am the replacement. I want to 
        access a scope variable: '+scope.model.myVariable+'
      </p>');
    newEle = $compile( element.contents() )(scope)
    element.replaceWith( newEle );
  };

  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      myVariable: '=someAttr'
    },
    link: postLink
  };
});
```

**Failing Test **

```
describe('my-replace', function() {
  var elm, scope, model, refreshElement, firstChild;

  firstChild = function( rootEle ) {
    return angular.element( rootEle.children()[0] );
  };

  beforeEach( module('MyApp') );

  beforeEach( function() {
    model = {
      myVariable: 'foobar'
    };

    inject(function($rootScope, $compile) {
      elm = angular.element(
        '<my-replace some-attr="model.myVariable">'
      );

      scope = $rootScope.$new();
      scope.model = model;
      $compile(elm)(scope);
      scope.$digest();
    });
  });

  it('replaces root element', function() {
    /**
     * This fails here, but it will work when run in a browser
     */
    expect( elm.prop('tagName') ).toBe( 'P' ); 
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `.replaceWith()` drops the reference to the original DOM element. Within the tests, `elm` no longer points to what's reflected in the actual DOM.

In order to get around this, the test data just needs to be wrapped in a container:

```
inject(function($rootScope, $compile) {
  elm = angular.element(
    '<div>' +
    '<my-replace some-attr="model.myVariable">' +
    '</div>'
  );
/* snip */
```

Now, directly replacing the element will reflect properly in the tests, when updated to search the child of the `<div>`.

Whether or not this sort of thing is a good practice, I'm still not entirely certain.